# Is ASP.NET vNext using same framework or totally different from previous framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to know that, whether ASP.NET vNext is using the same framework as the previous ASP.NET 
framework or is it a completely different from the earlier frameworks or is it built on the top of ASP.NET framework.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/getting-started-with-aspnet-vnext-and-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some changes to the architecture.

Earlier:

> CODE(c#, vb, j#)-> Compiler -> MSIL -> CLR -> Machine dependent code.

In vNext:

> CODE (c#, vb) -> Roslyn -> IL -> Kruntime -> CLR -> Machine dependent code.

For more details about Roslyn and Kruntime check bellow links

[aspnet home wiki](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki)

[.NET Compiler Platform](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Overview&referringTitle=Home)

For Architectural view you can see [here](http://www.programering.com/a/MDNxATNwATk.html)